# How to make width and height canvas equal to browser size in Iphone

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem related to width and height canvas in Iphone browser. In the first loading i am trying to make this code to make width and height canvas full page. The size is larg as expected, if the first loading in Portrait mode, but not in landscape mode. Is there another way to grab full size both Portrait and landscape.

```
     var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
     var canvasImage = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
         canvasMessage = document.getElementById("myCanvas2"),
         canvasImage.width = window.innerWidth;
         canvasImage.height = window.innerHeight; // on portrait it give 1091 but not in                                 landscape
         canvasMessage.width = window.innerWidth;
         canvasMessage.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

it may help you
Include this in your HTML page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"  />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193277/how-do-i-make-a-canvas-drawing-to-completely-fill-the-browser?rq=1